# CakePHP Drop Down Form Value Not Being Sent to Controller

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cakephp

I have a form with four fields - three of which are properly being sent up to the controller. One field is a drop-down selector field and it is not being sent. Here is sample form code from my schedule_date field which is being sent properly:

```
<?php
       echo $this->Form->input("schedule_date"
                                ,array('label'             => false
                                      ,'type'              => 'text'
                                      ,'class'             => 'step_dates'
                                      ,'readOnly'          => 'readOnly'
                                       )
                               );
   ?>
```

And here is the code for the drop-down box which is NOT being sent properly:

```
<?php
       echo $this->Form->input("project_step_type_id"
                               ,array('label'   => false
                                       ,'id'      => 'project_step_type_id'
                                       ,'class'   => 'project_step_type_id'
                                       ,'empty'   => '( select step )'
                                       ,'options' => $project_step_types
                                                                    )
                                                                );?>
```

Here is what my debug looks like on the form data I'm sending back (notice project_step_type_id is missing):

```
    <pre class="cake-debug">
array(
    &#039;user_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;402&#039;,
    &#039;trainer_user_id&#039; =&gt; &#039;524&#039;,
    &#039;schedule_date&#039; =&gt; &#039;2014-11-26&#039;
)
</pre>
```

Can anyone help? All fields are inside the form tag. I believe the issue is with this line:

```
            request_data=$('#my_form input').serializeCakeArray();
```

It's not getting the "select" fields, only the "input" fields. Does anyone know how to fix that? Thank you.

Comment: Is it inside the Form tag?

Comment: Serpes - yes, it is. Thank you for mentioning it though. :)

Comment: I believe the issue has something to do with this: 
            request_data=$('#my_form input').serializeCakeArray();

Comment: Can you post the View all please (where $this->Form) is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
request_data=$('#my_form input, #my_form select').serializeCakeArray();
```

Comment: oh yeah it s true and simple didnt notice it , for serialize the form just do $("#formId").serialize(); and it will be ok ( for textarea , select, input ...)